# How can I make a pointing to const int inside a string vector?

Tags: c++, pointers

I'm trying to make a program where customers info gets stored struct, and pointers. But I can't get a `vector<string>` to point to a const value.

```
struct customer { 
   string name;
   string email_address;
   int *subscription ????
}
```

I can add the customer name, and `email_address` but I'm trying to have the struct store the sold subscription. So for example someone bought a yearly subscription of television for const $100 a year. I add subscription then television then 100 it should display television(100). Customer can have multiple subscriptions stored in a `vector<string>`.

So

```
subscriptions = {television(100), internet(50),...,netflix(20)}.
```

so if ask to see what subscriptions a customer has, it displays these.

If I'm not really clear sorry English is not my first language.

Comment: I'm not sure why you say string and vector here, but write a pointer - they're not at all the same thing. You can just write `int const *` or `const int *` if you want a pointer to an integer whose value may not be changed via that pointer.

Comment: sorry ill rewrite the question. thanks for answering.

Comment: Why don't you use normal int (or int array) instead of a pointer? I believe your pointer has no valid address behind it.

Comment: its kind of a vector inside a vector. i thought pointers was the way to go. so its a vector where i can add subscriptions. and then in these subscriptions i can add the cost.

Comment: Could you show your logic when adding the subscription to the vector?

Comment: You can always just store the index into the vector instead of a raw pointer (since the index isn't invalidated when the vector resizes, unless you remove something before it). Or generate a customer key and just keep a `map<key, subscription>`

Comment: ill try. cout << add subscription << endl; cin  >> subscription >> endl; cin >> 100;

Comment: IIUC you want to store name/price pairs for every subscription, for which a `std::map<std::string, int>` is well-suited (assuming that a customer only has one of each kind of subscriptions at most - otherwise `std::multimap<std::string, int>`).

Answer (score -1):

Subscriptions should have information of both what he subscribed to and cost. int* is not sufficient to store both. one of the possible solutions may be creating subscription structure.

```
typedef struct subscription{
 string subscribed_to;
 int    cost;
 }subscription;

struct customer{
 string name;
 string email_id;
 int num_of_subscriptions;
 subscription subs[20];
};
```